# Cannot manipulate my files in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, permissions, mount, root

I am having major problems with my data partition which I have mounted at /home/data. Any time I try to download a file to any location within this folder I get a download failed error (with both Chrome and Firefox). If I try to delete files using the File Explorer, it will show them as getting deleted (the files will disappear from the folder) but when I leave and re-enter the folder the files are still there.

In the beginning I was getting errors that files were 'Read-only'. So I tried to remount the partition using

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point`

This seemed to solve the read-only issue, but it didn't fix the downloading/deleting/moving files issues.
When I run `ls -la` from the `/home` folder, it shows

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root   4096 Jan 10 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root   4096 Apr 16 13:01 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   8192 Apr 26 23:16 data
drwx------  2 root  root  16384 Jan  9 19:42 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 34 steve steve 4096 Apr 29 14:50 steve
```

Which leads me to believe that I still don't have ownership over the folder, so I tried to get ownership using `sudo chown steve:steve -vR data/` which gave me the following output for each file located in data

`changed ownership of 'data/' from root:root to steve:steve`

But the problem persists and the output of `ls -la` remains as:

```
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root   4096 Jan 10 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root   4096 Apr 16 13:01 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   8192 Apr 26 23:16 data
drwx------  2 root  root  16384 Jan  9 19:42 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 34 steve steve  4096 Apr 29 14:50 steve
```

I also tried `chmod 777 ./data` but this also hasn't helped. At this point I don't know what else to do.

Some extra info, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual boot with Windows. The computer was fine this morning but in the afternoon sometime is when it broke down, but I don't remember doing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: What was the exact chown command you used?

Comment: sudo chown steve -R ./data

Comment: have you tried `sudo chown steve:steve -R data/ ` ?

Comment: Just tried it, no difference

Comment: please try it with verbose and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1334890/edit) your original question with the output: `sudo chown steve:steve -vR data/`

Comment: Ok I have editted the question, but as you can see from what I added to the question, the problem still persists

Comment: can you put files in it as root? `su` then `touch /home/data/test`

Comment: I used sudo -i to log into root, but when in I got `touch: cannot touch '/home/data/test': No such file or directory`. The same when I tried to make it with mkdir.

Comment: Why did you all not ask if this partition is NTFS? :) Plus please do not ever use chmod 777. 750 is the max permissions you would need for personal storage.for DIRS and 640 for files. Setting all files to executable is bad and the same for "others" setting that to 7 is also bad. Next: putting a mount in /home/ is asking for trouble. If someone ever makes a user "data" and tells the system to create a /home for user data ... you got a serious problem If this is for steve you mount it in /home/steve/ but I would seriously use a mountpoint at / for the same reason userdel steve can remove content

Comment: @Rinzwind would remounting it at /data save me from needing to reformat it at this point?

Comment: And it does appear to be NTFS formatted, does this change anything?

Comment: If I was you I would mount your data at /home/steve/data. Mounting it at /home/data is within the root owned part of the filesystem. In the unlikely event that you created a user called data the system would want to use that point as the home folder for the data user.

Comment: @SteveAhlswede yes windows does not work with chmod so that command is moot. you set permissions when MOUNTING.  And why would you need to format the disk?!

Comment: Ya I was only going to reformat as a last option if I was totally unable to get the drive working again, but as you can see it luckily did not come to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to remount the partition in the recommended location from the comments I came across a new set of errors which led me to the eventual solution.

I had to run this series of commands

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /home/data
```

Now I have full r+w access again. The key here was the `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` command, as I guess the problem came from a windows restart or hibernation file that was present in the partition, and this command fixed that for me.

Comment: glad  to see you got it working again!